# Custom ListView TextView Items all show gray bar at top

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm having a problem with a custom ListView I am using in the ListActivity of my application.  My problem is that all TextView items added to the ListView through an ArrayAdapter show up with a gray bar above them.  I would include an image of the displayed ListView, but am unable since I do not have a reputation of 10 required by the stackoverflow site.

The layout file (index.xml) used to produce the ListView is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:divider="@color/mg_red" 
        android:dividerHeight="1sp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />


    <TextView 
        android:title="text_view"
        android:background="@drawable/listitemback"
        android:cacheColorHint="@drawable/listitemback"
        android:id="@+id/listItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:padding="10sp"    
        android:textColor="@color/listitemtext"
        android:textSize="16sp" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

The ListActivity code used to display the list is as follows:

```
public class IndexListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private ListView m_listView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        try 
        {
            if (MGApplication.DEBUG_BUILD)
            Log.i("TMG", "IndexListActivity.onCreate");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get our global data object.
        MGApplication mgApp = (MGApplication) getApplication();

        // Set view layout
        SetContentView(R.layout.index);

        // Get references to our ListView and AdView objects
        m_listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


            // Create a new ArrayAdapter object that will be used to initialize 
        // the underlying ListView object.
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.index,
                                                               R.id.listItem,
                                                               mgApp.m_strAZRhymeNames);

        // Assign array adapter
        m_listView.setAdapter(aa);
        }        
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return;
    }   
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am at my wits end with this issue.  I think I've tried every suggestion I could find on the web and I am unable to remove the gray bar.

Thank You,

Bob

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: YOU CAN TRY THIS android:scrollingCache="false"

Answer (score 0):

you have to set this property in **test.xml** file with.

```
     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_middle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:scrollingCache="false" />
```

and set some property in **listview object**.

```
lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

In my side that's work perfect.

Comment: None of the additional ListView attributes you identify correct the problem I am seeing.